# Julia: How to create subplots with different sizes using PyPlot?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, julia, subplot

I want to create a figure that contains multiple plots. However I want to be able to make each plot have a different size. For example, I want the first subplot to be approximately twice as wide as the second subplot. I was hoping to do something like this:

```
using PyPlot

a = rand(500,900)
b = rand(500,400)  # notice how 'a' is 900 in width and 'b' is 400, i.e. 'a' is approximately twice as wide as 'b'

figure(1)
subplot(2,5,1:2) ; imshow(a)
subplot(2,5,3) ; imshow(b)
# and so on...
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know of a method to allow me to adjust the size of each subplot?

Answer (score 3):

Similar to matlab, it is possible to have subplots of different sizes in the same figure window, as long as they don't overlap and they are defined in terms of a valid element in a valid grid. e.g.:

```
julia> subplot(2,2,1); imshow(a);
julia> subplot(2,4,3); imshow(b); # note the different grid size
```

However, if you want more precise control, then abandon the subplot command altogether, and manually draw your axes where you want them directly:

```
julia> axes([0.05, 0.55, 0.5,  0.4]); imshow(a);
julia> axes([0.6,  0.55, 0.35, 0.4]); imshow(b);
```

Comment: And, if you're anything like me, from my experience with matlab, once you've gotten the high of being completely in control of your axes and annotations, you'll never use the subplot command for serious work ever again, except when you want to quickly test something quick and dirty side-by-side and you don't care about fine-tuning. :p

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing is much easier using `Plots.jl`. See e.g. the `@layout` command in one of the first examples in [the documentation](https://juliaplots.github.io/).