# Reduce the size of pyplot subplot by scaling

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I am using Julia v.0.6.0, with Juno+Atom IDE, and I am trying to make subplots with `PyPlot` package, v2.3.2. (Pretty new to this)

Consider the following MWE:

```
using PyPlot

fig = figure("Test subplots",figsize=(9,9)) 
subplot(2,2,1) 
title("Plot 221")
fig[:add_subplot](2,2,2,polar="true")
title("Plot 222") 
fig[:canvas][:draw]() # Update the figure
suptitle("2x2 Subplot",fontsize=15)
tight_layout(pad=2)
```

which yields me this:

[image: subplots]

Note how the second subplot is too big such that its title is too close to the polar plot.

What I want to achieve is to have the subplot 222 to still take up the *same* amount of space in the grid, but to have the polar plot scaled down in size, perhaps to 0.9 of its current size. 
Note that this should not affect the size of rectangular grid in subplot 221 as well.

Is there an argument that I am missing from the matplotlib documentation?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40665391/4183191

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40856517/4183191

Comment: Ideally, I would prefer a `subplot` solution. That is, some options that I can pass *after* `subplot(222)`, for example. I'm not really fond of specifying the axes individually, but if there are no `scale` options for the subplot, then I suppose I would have to settle for this. It is not clear to me how I can continue drawing the plots with `axes`, can you write up an answer creating the 2 subplots I have in the attached image, but with `axes`?

Comment: If you're happy with using a different package, you could `using Plots; pyplot(); plot(2, proj = [:linear :polar], layout = 2)` to get the layout you request.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard My question was not about how to obtain the 1x2 layout.

Comment: My comment was not about that either. The Plots default layout looks as you request, with the polar plot reduced in size. But I'm sure you can find a PyPlot solution of course, so it was just a comment.

Comment: @ Troy: well I may be wrong of course, and there _may_ be some way to reduce the size of the polar grid ... but if it's anything like a normal cartesian plot (which I imagine it would be), the only way to reduce the size of the grid area is by scaling the axes. Unless you managed to use some sort of "grouping" object and then scale that. I have some idea how I might do such grouping in octave, but it's not something I've tried in matplotlib before. I can't make the example for you right now, but I'll see if I can make one a bit later if I have some time (and nobody else has answered already).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I'ld appreciate it, thanks! I should probably mention the polar plot is not essential in my question -- if it works for cartesian axes then it answers my qn as well.

Comment: @Troy, actually having looked a bit into the properties of the objects involved, you can easily resize things. I'll put an example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing here is to capture any subplot axes, title objects etc into 'handles', so that you can manipulate their properties individually in an easy manner. So change your initial code like so:

```
using PyPlot
fig = figure("Test subplots",figsize=(9,9)) 
subplot(2,2,1) 
title("Plot 221")
S = subplot(2,2,2,polar="true")               ## captured
T = title("Plot 222")                         ## captured
fig[:canvas][:draw]() # Update the figure
ST = suptitle("2x2 Subplot",fontsize=15)      ## captured
tight_layout(pad=2)
```

Now you can use properties such as `T[:get_verticalalignment]` to inspect, and `T[:set_verticalalignment]` to set it to one of "center", "bottom", "top" or "baseline" (as per the [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_verticalalignment)). E.g.

```
T[:set_verticalalignment]("bottom")
ST[:set_verticalalignment]("center")
```

seems to get the amount of separation you'd probably expect.

Alternatively, for even finer control, you can inspect or change the absolute positioning (and implicitly the size) for `S`, `T`, or `ST` via their `[:get_position]` and `[:set_position]` methods respectively.

These methods accept either via a normal array denoting `[start_x, start_y, width_x, width_y]`, or a [`Bbox`](https://matplotlib.org/api/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Bbox), which is the form returned by the `get` methods above, therefore you might want to get that object from matplotlib:

```
Bbox = PyPlot.matplotlib[:transforms][:Bbox]
```

Now you can do stuff like this:

```
# inspect the object's position
S[:get_position]()
#> PyObject Bbox([[0.544201388889, 0.517261679293], 
#>                [0.943952721661, 0.917013012065]])

# absolute positioning using 'width' notation
S[:set_position]([0.51, 0.51, 0.4, 0.4])   

# absolute positioning using a 'Bbox' (note 2D array input, not a vector!)
S[:set_position](Bbox([0.51 0.51; 0.89 0.89]))

# 'relative' by adjusting current position, and wrapping back in a Bbox
S[:set_position](Bbox( S[:get_position]()[:get_points]() + [0.1 0.1; -0.1 -0.1]))

# inspect title position
T[:get_position]()
#> (0.5, 1.05)

# raise title a bit higher (manually)
T[:set_position]([0.5, 1.10])
```

etc.